# Mapping class groups are finitely generated

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, mapping-class-groups

Let $N$ be a compact smooth manifold.  By "mapping class group" I will mean

$$\pi_0 \operatorname{Diff}(N)$$

i.e. the isotopy-classes of diffeomorphisms of $N$.

My presumption is that this mapping class group is likely to be finitely generated if and only if either $n = \dim N \leq 3$ or when $n \geq 4$ the group $\pi_1 N$ has finitely-many conjugacy classes, i.e. the path-components of the free loop space on $N$ are finite.

i.e. other than in low dimensions, finite-generation of the mapping class group corresponds to the fundamental group being finite.

Are there any obvious counter-examples to this statement I might be missing?  I'm wondering if it's a reasonable conjecture or not.  I would imagine this conjecture would remain the same in the PL and topological categories.  At least, all the non-finite-generation examples I know of are category-independent, and smoothing theory I believe would say this question is category-independent in high dimensions.

Comment: I think what you say is known in dimensions $\le 3$ (at least of for orientable manifolds). For prime 3-manifolds the mapping class group is known, and I think in the non-prime case the finite generation is also known (Hatcher says so in his 50 year diffeo groups survey). So the conjecture is really about dimensions $\ge 4$, and in this case it seems rather bold.

Comment: Anything could go wrong in dim 4 in my opinion.

Comment: While [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/ConcordanceSpaces.pdf) (among others) proved that the MCG of $T^6$ is not finitely generated, he cites [Hatcher-Lawson](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-43/issue-3/Stability-theorems-for-concordance-implies-isotopy-and-h-cobordism-implies/10.1215/S0012-7094-76-04345-3.short) that $T^6\#(S^3\times S^3)$ has pseudo-isotopy implies isotopy. Does this imply finitely generated MCG?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: perhaps, but from what we know so-far about mapping class groups of 4-manifolds, they appear to fit fairly coherently into the $n \geq 4$ family.  This could simply be ignorance, but it could also just be what it appears to be.

Comment: @BenWieland:  I am not certain.  I suspect there are diffeos of $T^6 \# (S^3 \times S^3)$ that are homotopic to the identity but not pseudo-isotopic to the identity. If so, this mapping class group is likely not-finitely generated.

Comment: This sounds very unlikely for hyperbolic manifolds. Mostow rigidity implies that the group of self-homotopy-equivalences is finite in dimension $\geq 3$. And I would guess that some suitably strong version of the Borel conjecture says that homotopy implies isotopy in this case. (But I’d be happy to understand why this guess is wrong!)

Comment: After a chat with Oscar Randal-Williams, I do indeed understand why my guess is wrong!

Comment: @HJRW: yes, the hyperbolic case and the argument behind it (barbell diffeos and things like it) is one of the key motivators of this question.

Comment: It seems like the finite fundamental group case should be within reach. It was not accessible to Sullivan without the K-theory and L-theory of finite groups, but with them it should not be much harder. I don't just say mutatis mutandis because there's the K/L theory introduces finitely generated abelian groups and there's a danger that the answer might be the kernel of a map from an arithmetic group to a finitely generated abelian group, and such a kernel could fail to be finitely generated. Has anyone written this down?

Comment: As for the infinite fundamental group case, this is completely out of reach. It is an open question whether there is an infinite finitely presented group with finitely many conjugacy classes, which would be a promising counterexample. What if we restrict to fundamental group $\mathbb Z$? If a manifold has higher homotopy groups that are not finitely generated, is its group of homotopy equivalences not finitely generated? Probably. Is its subgroup realizable by diffeomorphisms not finitely generated? Perhaps is it the kernel of a surjection to an arithmetic subgroup, which would show not fg.

Comment: @BenWieland: I'm a little confused about your first comment.  It sounds like you want to use the higher simple homotopy theory machine here, but it's not always applicable.  Are you restricting to some high-dimensional case?  The infinite fundamental group case I think is more accessible with current technology -- it's proven in a variety of cases, in all dimensions (although the 5-dimensional case isn't published yet).  That's much of the motivation for the thread.

Comment: Yes, high dimensions, like Sullivan. . . What do you mean by "a variety of cases"? A variety of fundamental groups, including $\mathbb Z$, or a variety of manifolds, $S^1\times S^n$, $S^1\times S^n \# S^a\times S^b$...?

Comment: Finite volume hyperbolic manifolds, $(S^1)^i \times D^j$ with $i \geq 1$, for starters.  There are a variety of connect-sums where it can be verified as well, although those details are not written up in a paper, at the moment.

Comment: @BenWieland: $T^6 \# S^3 \times S^3$ has an infinitely-generated subgroup of its mapping class group that remain non-trivial as homotopy-equivalences.

Answer (score 4):

For closed connected smooth manifolds $N$ of dimension $d \geq 6$ with $\pi_1(N)$ finite, it is known that $\pi_0(\mathrm{Diff}(N))$ has a classifying space which is a finite CW-complex. This is due to [Sullivan](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02684341) if $\pi_1(N)$ is trivial (this even works in dimension $d=5$) and to [Triantafillou](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1994-31-01/S0273-0979-1994-00496-3/) if $\pi_1(N)$ is finite. There were several oversights in her proof, which were corrected in a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-023-02594-x) by Mauricio Bustamante, Manuel Krannich, and myself.

Conversely, if $d \geq 6$ and $\pi_1(N)$ has infinitely many conjugacy classes not equal to their inverse then [Hsiang and Sharpe](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/67-2/p09.xhtml) proved under mild conditions that $\pi_0(\mathrm{Diff}(N))$ is not finitely generated. Some more groups can be handled by techniques from the Farell-Jones conjectures.

Ass I know the converse direction is not known in general, and in dimension $d=5$ both directions remain open. As you mention, the PL and topological cases imply the smooth case by smoothing theory if $d \geq 5$.

Comment: Your examples make me realize the conjecture probably should be that $\pi_1 N$ has finitely many conjugacy classes.  These barbell diffeo implantations are invariants of the path components of the free loop space on $N$.